# Google Sign in Fails

Tags: firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Forms Application where a user can sign in with Google.

The Google Sign in works fine in debug and Release Mode.
The Google Sign in works fine when I deploy the Application to my Android device or deploy it to Android Emulator.

The Problem occurs when I Archive the File into APK or AAB format.
When I deploy the Application on my Android Device through the APK File Generated by Archiving Google Authentication Fails.

I have created an Internal Testing on Google Play Console, by Uploading the Archived AAB file. The Internal Test also gives the Same Error Google Authentication Failed.
I have added the SHA-1 keys to the Firebase Console. and downloaded Google-Services. Json File and added it to my Android project. With build action as GoogleservicesJson.

I tried Adding the SHA-1 Fingerprint of the App Signing certificate to the FireBaseConsole/Settings/SHA Certificate Fingerprints

Comment: Are you using API key restrictions for the credentials in the Google Cloud Console? Don't forget to include all the fingerprints in there as well

Comment: My Android API key is restricted to Android Apps.

Comment: And did you make sure that the fingerprints are added in the Google API Console for those apps? I'm not talking about Firebase here.

Comment: Than you so muchI added all the Fingerprints in the Google cloud console.Now the Google Authentication works.Can you convert your comment to answer so that i could mark it as Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common pitfall, which happened to me a couple of times already as well.

Make sure that you don't only register the fingerprints for the different apps in Firebase, also make sure that you have the same fingerprints registered in the [Google API Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) of your app when working with API restrictions.

On the **Credentials** page, look for the desired API key, edit it and add the package names and fingerprints in the **Restrictions** section:

[image: Android Restrictions]

[image: Fingerprints]